# Jbuilder: How to encode an array of hashes?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, jbuilder

I want to encode the following JSON object using Jbuilder. How to do it?

```
    "should" : [
        {
            "term" : { "tag" : "wow" }
        },
        {
            "term" : { "tag" : "elasticsearch" }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 11):

Try the [child!](http://rubydoc.info/github/rails/jbuilder/Jbuilder:child!) method, e.g.

```
output = Jbuilder.encode do |json|
    json.should do
        json.child! do
            json.term { json.tag "wow" }
        end
        json.child! do
            json.term { json.tag "elasticsearch" }
        end
    end
end

puts output
```

Which will output:

```
{"should":[{"term":{"tag":"wow"}},{"term":{"tag":"elasticsearch"}}]}
```